# LUKS - change keyFile using cryptsetup

Tags: linux, disk-encryption, luks, dm-crypt

`cryptsetup` utility provides the option to change existing passphrase using **`luksChangeKey`** option. This requires the older key-file and other parameters as suggested on the man page.

> ```
>   luksChangeKey <device> [<new key file>]
>
>           Changes  an  existing  passphrase. The passphrase to be changed must be supplied interactively or via
>           --key-file.  The new passphrase can be supplied interactively or in a file given as positional  argu‐
>           ment.
>
>           If  a  key-slot is specified (via --key-slot), the passphrase for that key-slot must be given and the
>           new passphrase will overwrite the specified key-slot. If no key-slot is specified and there is  still
>           a  free  key-slot,  then the new passphrase will be put into a free key-slot before the key-slot con‐
>           taining the old passphrase is purged. If there is no free key-slot, then the key-slot  with  the  old
>           passphrase is overwritten directly.
>
>           WARNING:  If a key-slot is overwritten, a media failure during this operation can cause the overwrite
>           to fail after the old passphrase has been wiped and make the LUKS container inaccessible.
>
>           <options> can be  [--key-file,  --keyfile-offset,  --keyfile-size,  --new-keyfile-offset,  --new-key‐
>           file-size, --key-slot, --force-password, --header].
> ```

When I run it, it prompts for the **passphrase**. But I need to use **another key file**.

Where is the option of providing new key file? From the man page, I can understand,

- **`--keyfile`**: older key file
- **`--keyfile-offset`**: older key file offset
- **`--keyfile-size`**: older key file offset
- **`--new-keyfile-offset`**: new key file offset
- **`--new-key‐file-size`**: new key file size

I know there is another way of changing passphrase by using **luksAddKey** (new key) and then **luksRemoveKey** (previous one). But, I'm asking specifically for **luksChangeKey**.

Comment: The 1st line of your quote seems to have the answer.

Answer (score 3):

No idea why @studiohack voted down / deleted my answer (and no idea howto sent direct communications here and I am not paid by superuser.com so my time here is limited).

But the ANSWER was/is right - only with notification that it MAY NOT WORK for actual version cryptsetup 1.7.3:

And its independent if I use the luksAddKey OR luksChangeKey command - the parameters WORKS SAME WAY:

It was working fine with e.g. this example with Debian Jessie using cryptsetup 1.6.6 (didn't know anymore the reference I found last year):

```
echo -n "yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" | \
cryptsetup luksAddKey --key-file - --keyfile-offset 0 --keyfile-size 32 \
                      --new-keyfile-offset 32 --key-slot 0 /dev/sda2
```

- key file: - (STDIN)
- using key: yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy (32 bytes size from byte offset 0)
- adding key: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx (32 bytes size from byte offset 32)

But it seems not working anymore with Debian Stretch using cryptsetup 1.7.3
(and the rest of the information was NOT A QUESTION but a statement of the actual behavior).

Comment: I don't know what happened, but your current answer is about providing a keyfile using stdin which was not asked. So it is in fact off-topic

Answer (score 2):

The answer is in your question, just read carefully:

There are 5 named parameters (3 for the old and 2 for the new keyfile), plus the one missing *unnamed* parameter:

```
luksChangeKey <device> [<new key file>]
```

So your command (if you use all options) will look like this:

```
luksChangeKey <device> --keyfile <oldkeyfile> --keyfile-offset <oldoffset> --keyfile-size <oldsize> --new-keyfile-offset <newoffset> --new-key‐file-size <newsize> <newkeyfile>
                                                                                                                                                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

and the more likely short form:

```
luksChangeKey <device> --keyfile <oldkeyfile> <newkeyfile>
                                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```